# Can't set variables before plugins{}

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have this `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse-wtp'
}

[...]

dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-dependencies', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'

[...]
```

I would specify a variable `springBootVersion = "2.1.6.RELEASE"`. Unluckily, this is not possible, since I get this error:

> only buildscript {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed
>   before plugins {} blocks

I also tried to remove the version from `spring-boot-dependencies` but I get this error:

> Could not resolve: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies

Is there not a way to declare a variable before the `plugin{}` block, or, alternatively, remove the version from `spring-boot-dependencies`?

I'm using Gradle 5.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use variables in the plugins block. Check the "Strict Syntax" section here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugin/use/PluginDependenciesSpec.html
also:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3593

You shouldn't need to define the spring boot version anywhere else than in the plugins block by applying the spring boot plugin(org.springframework.boot) and then applying the (io.spring.dependency-management) after the block. The latter one then will take care of resolving the right versions based on the boot plugin version.

If don't know about it yet, I suggest to use the https://start.spring.io/ to generate your spring boot project, because it can generate you a ready-to-go gradle project.

Comment: Yes, the problem is I added `spring-boot-dependencies`, while I already have the plugin `io.spring.dependency-management`. Anyway I do not understand why I was not able to remove the version from `spring-boot-dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
plugins {
    ext.springBootVersion = '2.1.6.RELEASE' 
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version springBootVersion
    ... 
}

[...]

dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${plugins.springBootVersion}@pom"
```

Comment: Error: `only id(String) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block`. Have you at least tried the code?

Comment: "Have you at least tried the code?" Nope, hence why I said "perhaps"

Answer (score 0):

Using buildscript you can do this:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.6.6'
  }
}
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
}
```